# What is the purpose of testing if a React button successfully calls a function given to onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, automated-tests

The test in the code below is a very common pattern I have seen both online and at a company I interned at:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Button from './Button';

describe('Test Button component', () => {
  it('Test click event', () => {
    const mockCallBack = jest.fn();

    const button = shallow((<Button onClick={mockCallBack}>Ok!</Button>));
    button.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(mockCallBack.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

What I don't understand is why bother writing this test? If a component has an onClick property, and onClick is supplied a callback, of course clicking that component will result in the callback being called. When would this ever fail? What am I not considering here?

Comment: I'm with you, lol. If a test doesn't provide business value, I don't see any reason to spend time on it. Oftentimes people spend too much time trying to hit an arbitrary code coverage metric to feel good about their code. In my opinion, test mission critical business logic and call it a day.

Comment: You may want to assert *your* UI code correctly passes a value *to the passed callback*, not simply that is was called. Hopefully your test snippet is a super simplified example. In general I think it's good advice to not test the language you're using and don't test third party code.

Comment: @DrewReese, I agree with that scenario described being a valuable test. But no, what I described in my original question is not simplified, that exact pattern, a mock call back being called, is exactly the test and hence my confusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this test testing two things:

1. Button calls provided onClick handler, if your teammate perform some refactoring in Button component and forgot to provide onClick function to native button element this test will fail. This kind of problem will be discovered in PR when someone review changes or in testing but none of this two guarantees you that broken button wont appear in production.
2. Button renders, i.e. some library that you use to style that Button is broken, it is common case in javascript world. `then/is-promise` 1-liner library with 11+ million usages has been [broken](https://github.com/then/is-promise/issues/13) today. So if you test code it will fall locally or on CI before you merge it.

But with shallow rendering second case wont work as expected here because it doesn't render all components in the react tree with running all lifecycle hooks, it is considered as bad practice in testing, you can checkout post by Kent C Dodds [Why I never use shallow rendering](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/why-i-never-use-shallow-rendering) for more details.

It is important part of *testing culture* to test everything, the code is not working until you test it, if your code is simple, the test will be simple too. It is good code. If your code is entangled and complicated most likely you won't be able to write a test for your code at all. You will have to refactor it to make it testable and simple. It is praiseworthy that you are thinking about the meaning of the test, sometimes tests can be useless but your example is not.

Comment: wow @gzaripov. great points and thank you so much. very enlightening. this has always bothered me so it's good to know now i am not writing code for the sake of it. also the difference with shallow rendering is a great point too, i will follow the pattern of not doing shallow renders from now on.